# Source code of Chrome Mobile start page

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I would like to see the source code of Chrome start page on Mobile phone, which shows the google search bar and 8 tiles of preferred websites.

Any idea where I could find it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Click here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.dev&hl=en) and install Chrome Dev on your PC.
Open it and then following the instructions on [this site](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/), activate mobile mode. Then simply view source code as you would for any other site.